# Email piping through to Junk folder

Tags: email, spam

I have a personal business email that I know sometimes pipes to junk, even if I've shared correspondence previously with the recipient. I'm doing all I can to fix this but in the meantime I've set up a Gmail address to use either as primary or follow up to check with the recipient.

My question is: if my primary email address has piped to junk will the second email do the same if the address contains the same characters?

eg.
primary email: john@joebloggs.com
secondary email: joebloggs.com@gmail.com

Comment: Typically the domain name component (and the mail servers used to send from that domain) is what contributes most to a bad sender score and the username component very little.

Comment: ah that's good to know, thanks for your reply.